# Retry ssh with multiple user for a host in ansible

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

I have 200+ running Ec2s instances. All are launched with same key, but user is different some are with ec2-user,some are with ubuntu etc. I have to write a playbook to perform a tasks on all running instances but how i will specify ansible_user, is there any way where i can mention multiple user and ansible will retry with all listed user.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

In the inventory file, you can specify the user.

```
leafs:
  hosts:
    leaf01:
      ansible_host: 10.16.10.11
      ansible_network_os: vyos.vyos.vyos
      ansible_user: my_vyos_user
    leaf02:
      ansible_host: 10.16.10.12
      ansible_network_os: vyos.vyos.vyos
      ansible_user: my_vyos_user
```

You can also group like the below:

```
leafs:
  hosts:
    leaf01:
      ansible_host: 10.16.10.11
    leaf02:
      ansible_host: 10.16.10.12
  vars:
    ansible_network_os: vyos.vyos.vyos
    ansible_user: my_vyos_user
```

You can find more details at: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/network/getting_started/first_inventory.html

Comment: Thanks Aakhil, but i am creating dynamic inventory, to assign ansible_user for a host or a group of host i need a logic to find ssh user (here it is based on ami, possible value of user are centos,ubuntu,ec2-user).

Comment: What is 'ami'? How are the users based on 'ami'?

Comment: all instances has ami from aws market place. Ubuntu AMI has login user ubuntu, centos ami has user centos. And i have to do ssh using these user into instances . As i mentioned launched key are same for all instances.

Comment: See [Amazon.Aws collection](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/amazon/aws/index.html#plugins-in-amazon-aws) (For the record. ``AMI = Amazon Machine Images``).

Comment: @Ankit You can combine dynamic and static inventory files.  The hosts should be separated by group based on AMI, and use static `group_vars` files to set the username.

Comment: You can also tag the every instance with the login name and use that tag in your playbook.